# Rails API - LoadError in API::V1::UsersController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to add a simple JSON API to my APP

```
#routes.rb
namespace :api, :format => :json do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end


#controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with User.all
  end
end


#inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

`rake routes` gives me the following:

```
api_v1_users        GET      /api/v1/users(.:format)             api/v1/users#index
                    POST     /api/v1/users(.:format)             api/v1/users#create
new_api_v1_user     GET      /api/v1/users/new(.:format)         api/v1/users#new
edit_api_v1_user    GET      /api/v1/users/:id/edit(.:format)    api/v1/users#edit
api_v1_user         GET      /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)         api/v1/users#show
                    PATCH    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)         api/v1/users#update
                    PUT      /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)         api/v1/users#update
                    DELETE   /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)         api/v1/users#destroy
```

When I visit `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users` I got the following error:

> **LoadError in API::V1::UsersController#index Unable to autoload**
>   constant API::V1::UsersController, expected
>   /path/to/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb to define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says exactly what to do. Make sure you use `API` instead of `Api` in your controller name.

```
#  == HERE ==
class API::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with User.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. Now I got other errors, which I will try to solve by myself (or I will open specific questions on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Or second way declare another acronym, or remove it anyway:

**inflections.rb**:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.acronym 'Api'
end
```